# Условие в джаве

Tags: android, java

Ребята не могу понять почему не выполняется условие в следующем коде

```
public class OtvetActivity extends Activity {

    String pref;

    private static final String MY_SETTINGS = "my_settings";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.otvet);

        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MY_SETTINGS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String table_sql = sp.getString("table_mess", "");
        if (table_sql=="messages_moscow") {pref="mes77";}
        else if (table_sql=="messages_spb") {pref="mes78";}
        else if (table_sql=="messages_abakan") {pref="mes19";}
        else {pref="no_pref";}

        TextView table_sql_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prefsnow);
        table_sql_text.setText(pref);

    }
}
```

Смысл в том, что переменная table_sql здесь содержит значение "messages_abakan" и в данном случае должна присвоить переменной pref значение mes19, но однако скрипт выдает надпись no_pref, что означает, что совпадений не было, хотя совподение сто процентов есть, в чем дело?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно писать table_sql.equals("messages_abakan") вместо table_sql=="messages_abakan"

При сравнении через оператор == сравниваются ссылки на объект, т.е. указывают ли сравниваемые переменные на один и тот же объект. А метод equals сравнивает значения объектов.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй строки сравнивать с помощью equals